# Fragment. getViewLifeCycleOwner doesn't prevent multiple calls of LiveData Observer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-livedata

I use Clean Architecture, LiveData, Navigation component & Bottom Navigation view.
I am creating a simple application with **three tabs**. By default, the First tab Fragment loads user data using some API. When i go to another tabs and then return to the First tab Fragment, i see, that `observe` return a new data!

I need `observe` not to return data again when I switch back to the first tab! what am I doing wrong? Could you help me please?

P.s. For navigation i use sample from [navigation-advanced-sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample) and after switching tabs `onDestroy` is not called.

**First solution** in the article [Observe LiveData from ViewModel in Fragment](https://blog.usejournal.com/observe-livedata-from-viewmodel-in-fragment-fd7d14f9f5fb) said:

> One proper solution is to use getViewLifeCycleOwner() as LifeCycleOwer while observing LiveData inside onActivityCreated as follows.

I use following code, but it's not work for me:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    Timber.d("onActivityCreated")
    viewModel.getProfileLive().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
}
```

**Second solution** in the article [Architecture Components pitfalls — Part 1](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808) recommends using *Resetting an existing observer* and *Manually unsubscribing the observer in onDestroyView()*. But it doesn't work for me either...

**ProfileFragment.kt**

```
class ProfileFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: ProfileFragmentViewModel

    private val observer = Observer<Resource<Profile>> {
        when (it.status) {
            Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                Timber.i("Loading...")
            }
            Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                Timber.i("Success: %s", it.data)
            }
            Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                Timber.i("Error: %s", it.message)
            }
        }
    };

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("onCreate")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Timber.d("onCreateView")
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    }

    fun <T> LiveData<T>.reObserve(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
        removeObserver(observer)
        observe(owner, observer)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("onViewCreated")
        viewModel.getProfileLive().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
        // viewModel.getProfileLive().reObserve(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("onActivityCreated")
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        Timber.d("onDestroyView")
        // viewModel.getProfileLive().removeObserver(observer)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Timber.d("onDestroy")
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        Timber.d("onDetach")
    }
}
```

**ProfileFragmentViewModel.kt**

```
class ProfileFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val profileUseCase: ProfileUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        Timber.d("Init profile VM")
    }

    fun getProfileLive() = profileUseCase.getProfile()
}
```

**ProfileUseCase**

```
class ProfileUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val profileRepository: ProfileRepository
) {

    fun getProfile(): LiveData<Resource<Profile>> {
        return profileRepository.getProfile()
    }
}
```

**ProfileRepository.kt**.
class ProfileRepository @Inject constructor(
private val loginUserDao: LoginUserDao,
private val profileDao: ProfileDao,
) {

```
fun getProfile(): LiveData<Resource<Profile>> =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
        emit(Resource.loading(data = null))

        val profile = profileDao.getProfile()

        // Emit Success result...
    }
```

}

Comment: LiveData always caches the last result and redelivers it, that has nothing to do with the lifecycle of your Observers (which are already correct when using `getViewLifecycleOwner()`).

Comment: @ianhanniballake and what's right way to correct solve this problem?

Comment: "i see, that observe return a new data" what is actually the problem with that? "I need observe not to return data again" why?

Comment: @Tobi Let's pretend you're using Instagram. And every time you switch tabs, a new request is made to load the feed and other items. And in my simple application, navigation should work in a similar way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the API to be called again on switching tabs, correct?

Comment: @SarahKhan no, i don't want it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of how **Fragment Lifecycle** works. When you move to and fro from a fragment `onViewCreated()` is called again. In `onViewCreated` you're calling `viewModel.getProfileLive()` which returns the livedata upto from the **repository** and **observe** to it.

Since `onViewCreated()` gets called everytime when you move back to the **Fragment** so is your call to `viewModel.getProfileLive()` and in turn the **repository** gets called again which again triggers the `observe` method in your Fragment.

In order to solve this problem,
create a **LiveData** variable in your **ViewModel**, set it to the returned **Live Data** from **Repository**.
In the **Fragment** observe to the **LiveData variable** of your **ViewModel** not the one returned from **Repository**.
That way, your `observe` method will get triggered on very first time and only when **value** of your data from **repository** changes.

Comment: long story short: load the data in the constructor of your viewmodel not in your fragments oncreate

Comment: Long story so that he could understand what was wrong.

Comment: absolutely, sometimes it helps to sum it up in a sentence in the end to stop potential confusion ;)

Comment: Thank you! Is just what it's needed

Comment: If I need to update the data, what is the correct way to do it in this case?

Comment: `private val _result = MutableLiveData<ResourceState<ModelClass>>()
val result: LiveData<ResourceState<ModelClass>> = _result`

Observing result in the fragment and using _result to get result from the repo and updating it ViewModel.

The issue I'm facing is that when coming back to fragment A from B observe gets trigger again.